# How to store JWT and give user access using Laravel 5.2 + Guzzle 6

Tags: api, laravel, jwt, guzzle

I am pretty new on Laravel + Guzzle + JWT.
Well, I came across with a project which requires to consume an API that is already running.

I could get every data I need from API using Guzzle such as JWT itself, user details, etc.

My worry is, how should I store this token to make future calls and how can give permission to users to access restricted pages?

I think it can be used Laravel Auth, but how?

Plus, the API accepts Facebook, Twitter and email logins. Is there a way to combine everything using Laravel Auth?

Could someone give an overview or provide a link? I am a bit lost, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete step by step article that I used to authenticate by  jwt in laravel as backend and angularjs as frontend.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs

Thanks to Ryan and Tino

Comment: That is the problem, I am not using Angular. I am using Guzzle to make the request and get the JWT. After that I do not know what I should do to give access to users.